# How do I resolve slow and choppy performance in virtualbox?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, virtualization

Ubuntu runs very slowly inside of VirtualBox.

How do I run Ubuntu with unity or enabled transparency smoothly with VirtualBox?

Answer (score 29):

Graphic/performance fix for Ubuntu was tested with Ubuntu 13.04, 12.10, and 12.04. Part of this solution applies where aero / transperancy is used including d3d games.

#### RAM requirements

Recommended graphic memory or virtual ram for aero based operating systems is 256 MB min.ram -768 MB for 13.04

#### Virtual machine settings

1. enable 3d support in virtualbox 3d settings
2. terminal commands:

   ```
   /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
   ```

   (Not software rendered:no, unity 3d support:No)

   ```
   uname -r
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```

   now insert vitualbox guest iso from devices and to install manually follow

   ```
   cd /media
   ls
   cd username
   ls
   cd VBOX*
   ls
   sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

   sudo gedit /etc/modules
   ```

   add "vboxvideo" in the next line after lp means `loop>lp>vboxvideo` like this click save and file quit
3. restart the machine
4. now open the terminal to checkunity 3d is enabled or not

   ```
   /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
   ```
5. after this shut down the machine lets increase the virtual ram
6. close virtual machine and virtual box
7. follow this path `C:\Users\Username\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu 13.04`
8. now look for ".vbox" extension file and open it with temporarily with wordpad
9. look for the following lines and replace these in following manner

   ```
   Display VRAMSize="128" monitorCount="1" accelerate3D="true" accelerate2DVideo="false"/>
   ```

   to

   ```
   Display VRAMSize="256" monitorCount="1" accelerate3D="true" accelerate2DVideo="false"/>
   ```
10. now you can set 256 mb virtual memory for this operating system.
11. any OS can be provided with desired vram this way

#### Reference and sources::

babarehner @ e-wrench.com and youtube

sanct on http://ubuntuforums.org/forum.php

rpxmac on [forums.virtualbox.org](https://forums.virtualbox.org)

#### Related questions on Ask Ubuntu

[How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745)
[How do I enable hardware virtualization technology (VT-x) for use in Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox)
[Ubuntu installation in VirtualBox - not using base memory in RAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254647/ubuntu-installation-in-virtualbox-not-using-base-memory-in-ram)

Comment: FYI, you can change those VRAM and other settings through the VirtualBox UI now.

Comment: Can't find `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` anywhere?

Comment: @ashes999 But only to 128MB

Comment: Failed to open a session for the virtual machine kali linux.

VRamSize is too large, 0x20000000, max 0x10000000 (VERR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {}

This isn't working.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you enable 3D support on Virtualbox, and on guest Ubuntu virtualbox setting. Also give your virualbox enough RAM and cpu cores. Having dedicated VGA will help virtualbox performance as well. [How to fix slow performance ubuntu 13.04 running in virtualbox](http://namhuy.net/951/how-to-fix-slow-performance-ubuntu-13-04-running-in-virtualbox.html)

Comment: The article linked to here is broken. Does anyone happen to know the working one?

Comment: Archive.org has it in the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160512071115/http://www.namhuy.net:80/951/how-to-fix-slow-performance-ubuntu-13-04-running-in-virtualbox.html