# How can I fix it so my system doesn't crash whenever i go to "System Settings > Details"?

Tags: 13.04, system-settings

How can I fix it so my system doesn't crash whenever i go to "System Settings > Details"?  Or even where/how would I go about troubleshooting the issue? Thanks!

Edit:  When running control center from the terminal and then clicking on "Details" I get the following:

```
(gnome-control-center:9579): info-cc-panel-WARNING **: PackageKit version 7.4.0 not supported
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0xb8625e50
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Getting the same thing :(

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-control-center/+bug/1179659. There is a patch posted, but hopefully the fix will be pushed to Raring.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem in Ubuntu 13.04 running as VirtualBox guest. It happened after I tried to enable Unity 3D support as described in the article [How do I resolve slow and choppy performance in virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287532/how-do-i-resolve-slow-and-choppy-performance-in-virtualbox) .