# No Unity, launcher and dash on Ubuntu 13.04 within VirtualBox4.2.12 after enabel 3D Acceleration

Tags: unity, 13.04, virtualbox, performance, 3d

I was using Ubuntu 12.10 in my VirtualBox4.2.12 on my Windows7 Host. They worked good. But when I install Ubuntu 13.04 in VirtualBox 4.2.12, the screen and display are very slow. I have followed this post <[How do I resolve slow and choppy performance in virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287532/how-do-i-resolve-slow-and-choppy-performance-in-virtualbox/287760#287760)> to enable 3D Acceleration.

Now the performance issue is resolved, but the Unity, launcher and dash are gone. I have tried to disable 3D Acceleration, the Unity can be displayed, but the performance issue come again. Please see my screenshot.

[image]

Is there anyone has the same issue? I have searched the answer from this site, all the answers are pointed to  [How do I resolve slow and choppy performance in virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287532/how-do-i-resolve-slow-and-choppy-performance-in-virtualbox)

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, probably the problem is in Unity's desktop environement, try installing another one... GNOME 3 is probably one of the best ones out there... To install it,

1. Press ctrl+alt+T
2. Then Type the following commands:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

Then logout of your account, and click on the little Ubuntu icon right next to your login username, and select GNOME 3...

That should do, if you still have problems with performance, check for the resources you're giving to your virtual computer, (Ram, etc...)

Many people have problems with Ubuntu 13.04, so don't worry, the Ubuntu team should fix those errors soon...

Comment: Thanks that's really help. Hope they can fix those errors soon.

Comment: Isn't enough to: sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

Comment: Those issues are still not solved even in Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, what I do to be able to work when that happens is to log out, and log into Guest account, the log on again in my account, and Unity works again.

It's an ugly  workaround but may be helpful.

To log out you will have to guess the position of the "gear" Icon on the top Right corner
to click it.