# Running downloaded Ubuntu on VirtualBox is so very slow? What to do?

Tags: virtualbox

I downloaded VirtualBox onto my Windows 7 machine after which I successfully downloaded Ubuntu v 14, which I updated to v.15. However, I find that Ubuntu runs very very slowly and that the @ sign does not seem to be recognized. Do I have to pay a yearly subscription to get Ubuntu to work optimally? If so to whom?

Comment: What amount of RAM did you assigned to the virtual machine? Where did you found Ubuntu "v.15" ?

Comment: Her's what you can try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/289677/how-to-improve-performance-of-virtualbox-when-unity-low-gfx-mode-is-not-working

Comment: [Why does a Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox run very, very slowly?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/207813/why-does-a-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox-run-very-very-slowly?rq=1) and [How do I resolve slow and choppy performance in virtualbox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287532/how-do-i-resolve-slow-and-choppy-performance-in-virtualbox)

Answer (score 1):

First of all  Ubuntu is 100% Free. And latest ubuntu is 14.04 so there is not 15 version.
If you are running ubuntu in virtual-box then check the amount  of RAM Allocated  to ubuntu.
Ubuntu need minimum 1 GB RAM and 700 MHz processor.