# Virtualbox laggy despite having enabled hardware acceleration

Tags: unity, graphics, virtualbox, performance

I spun up an Ubuntu 16.10 instance on VirtualBox 5.1.6 within Windows 10. I've allocated it 2 GB of the host's 8 GB RAM, and 2 of 4 cores. I found Ubuntu's GUI so choppy, as to be unusable. After a quick Google search, I followed and completed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287532/how-do-i-resolve-slow-and-choppy-performance-in-virtualbox) guide to enable hardware acceleration. I dedicated 256 MB of VRAM to the VM to no performance gain.

Here's the output from unity support test:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Chromium 1.9

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Relevant line in .vbox file:

```
      <Display VRAMSize="256" accelerate3D="true"/>
```

What can I do make Ubuntu run at a usable speed?